# Best UI for Search/Filter/Boolean expression

Tags: user-interface, filtering

There are some simple ones, some complex ones, but I cannot find the gold standard. 
Can anyone point me to "the best" way to let a user define a search criteria (or filter) to retrieve results?

This is complicated since:

- Need to support about 10 different types of elements
- Support And, Or, Not
- Parenthesis (a killer to 95% of the population)

As an example I looked at MorningStar premium fund filter, it is ok but not web2.0 (ajax, JQuery.. in other words, not cool) and it handles parenthesis poorly.

Answer (score 11):

Check Smart Playlists in iTunes. I find this UI very clear.

Finder in OS X has similar GUI, but also allows nested "parentheses" by pressing *Alt* and `(+)`/`(-)`.

Comment: I'm curious: how did you find out about the nested parentheses thing? How much guidance is there in the UI to tell the user how to use the filtering feature as a whole? Thanks.

Comment: I suppose pressing Alt whenever application does *almost* what you want is a Mac thing. Discoverability of this feature could certainly be improved, e.g. by including a visible button for this.

Comment: While I agree with the above two comments, all I did was press the (?) button on the smart playlist editor UI, and it had a screenshot with everything labeled clearly. I think for anyone willing to take the time to do an advanced search (power users), this isn't too much to expect.